# Model partial differential equation problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider a infinite rod with the temperature at a specific time $u(x,t)$ if the initial temperature is constant in $(-2,2)$ and and zero outside.

I need the boundary and initial conditions for the above mentioned situation.

I know for sure that the boundary condition outside the cross-section must be the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{|x|\to\infty} u(x,t)=0$.

Not sure about the inside,
is it 
$u(x,0) = A$ and $u(x,0) = B$ or $u(-2,0) = A$ and $u(2,0) = B$ (where $A$ and $B$ are constant).

Can someone please exchange their insight and say if I'm on the right trail?

Comment: Are you looking for more guidance on the solution, or is what I stated all you need?

Comment: So the boundary condition outside was fine what I gave? I will solve the problem using the Fourier transformation method!

Comment: It was not really fine as given - what I gave below is more like it.  Yes, go with Fourier on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are given the boundary condition as you specify, and an *initial* condition as follows:

$$u(x,0) = \begin{cases} A & |x| \lt 2 \\ 0 & |x| \gt 2\end{cases}$$

That is sufficient to solve the equation and get a unique solution.